# Getting multiple results from search with single Wikipedia (MediaWiki) API call

Tags: php, mediawiki, wikipedia

I've been searching Wikipedia (:Mediawiki) api for the next option and could not found whether it does or does not exist ;
I'd like to search for "Sydney NSW Australia" (for example , search query is changed up to user's search query).
There is not specific wikipedia page for "Sydney NSW Australia" but there is a page for Sydney and there is one for NSW and Australia too.

If there is no specific page for the original search query, i'd like to get the content of the pages of Sydney or NSW or Australia ( without sending multiple queries).

Is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `intitle:Sydney OR intitle:NSW OR intitle:Australia`. You will get some problems with NSW, because that page redirects to New South Wales.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer. How should the query look like using "intitle"?  Is it an actual searching parameter ? Thanks.

Comment: NSW is actually New South Wales :)

Comment: I know, but it does not show in the search results (or at least it's quite a way down).

Comment: pass `intitle:Sydney OR intitle:NSW OR intitle:Australia` as  `srsearch` parameter (after properly URL-encoding it).

Comment: For begginers: in the url quering the api you can use pipe : Sydney|NSW|Australia to search all three words.